# Length of argument inside a function of an sh script

Tags: shell, string, variable

I have a FreeBSD 9.3 RELEASE server and I am trying to write a shell script using `sh`.
I am trying to get the length of a variable that is passed to a function in a shell script, like so:

```
#!/bin/sh

myfunc() {
  varlength=${#1}
  echo $varlength
}

test="aaaaa aaaaa"
myfunc $test
```

The above script should return 11, which is the length of the test variable, but ${#1} does not seem to work. I have also tried many other ways to accomplish that but i can't figure it out.

```
varlength=$(expr ${#1})  does not work
varlength=$(${#1})  does not work
varlength=$(expr \( "X$1" : ".*" \) - 1)  does not work
varlength=$({#1})  does not work
```

and many many other attempts I made failed.

Comment: Can you try declaring the script as bash in the she-bang? Like this: `#!/usr/bin/env bash`

Comment: Instead of trying to do it with a shell built-in, you could always echo it and pipe it to the "wc -c" program to count the characters. Slightly more expensive of course.

Comment: `${#1}` is defined in posix. I don't know what shell you're using, but it should work. What is happening when you run it? Error, no output, what? The result I expect is `5`.

Comment: The script is rather long and declaring it as bash would mean that I have to spend some time making sure it works, since it is written with sh in mind. Piping it to wc would require that I export the variable to a file and passing that file as an argument to wc which is indeed more expensive. ${#1} is indeed defined in POSIX. The result I get is also 5, but as you can see it is wrong. The actual length of the variable is 11. After 11 hours scripting, I might be missing something that is obvious to someone else, that is why I asked here. Thank you for your replies.

Comment: No, piping to `wc` does not require writing the variable to a file; just do `varlength=$(echo "$1" | wc -c)`. (You'll want to subtract 1 from the result, because it will count the newline. Or, do `echo -n "$1"` or `echo -e "$1\c"` -- but not if `$1` might contain backslashes.)

Comment: Ok, i didn't know that. I guess i should read man wc. Thank for the tip.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

because `$test` contains whitespace, when you say

```
myfunc $test # without quotes
```

your function receives > 1 argument. myfunc receives 2 arguments here, `aaaaa` and  `aaaaa`.

You want this:

```
myfunc "$test" # with quotes
```

Rule of thumb: **always** quote your `"$variables"` unless you know exactly when and why not to.

Comment: Interesting. In zsh, $test will expand to a single positional argument (with an embedded space). But ksh performs as you suggest as well.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I will try this tomorrow first thing when I get to work and let you know whether it worked.

Comment: @BobDoolittle, look for "Field Splitting" in the ksh93 man page: http://www2.research.att.com/sw/download/man/man1/ksh.html

Comment: It worked as expected. Thank you very much.